# How to display different statusbar color in different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-statusbar, android-color

I have 20 fragments in my android application.

There are two fragments which have `CollaspingToolbarLayout` - i want this fragment's statusbar color as like their CollaspingToolbar color which is primarycolor

Other eighteen fragments have `Toolbar` - i want this fragment's statusbar color as like their toolbar color which is white

I can do it by adding this in each fragments but I have to add this in all the fragments.

```
GetActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(//color here//);
```

Is there any other way to do so? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: extend all of them with BaseFragment so you can control it in a better way

Comment: How about setting `StatusBar` color back to white when closing the your fragments which have `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ? In this way, you do not need to touch other 18 fragments. You only touch the 2 fragment.

Comment: It works!!!  Thanks @AzizjonKholmatov You can answer the question. I will marked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is very specific.

You can set `StatusBar` color back to white when closing your fragments which have `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. In this way, you do not need to touch other 18 fragments. You only touch only those 2 fragments.

Note: I really recommend to have a parent activity or fragment which have dedicated methods for such actions. It makes your code clean and more readable.

Comment: Thanks but i am facing one other problem now.

Comment: When i set other fragment status bar color white all the statusbar element doesn't display. How can i make it black.

Comment: I have try to set flag using getDecorView() method but  it is not working

Comment: @bhumivaghasiya Were the colors of the `StatusBar` text and icons white before you set the color white to `StatusBar`?